# How to setup React-Testing-Library with Redux-RTK (in typescript)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux to manage the state for my components. While it works on my application, I cannot get it to work within my **react-testing-library** testing suite.

Good news is, `Redux-RTK` has documentation for setting up their library with `react-testing-library` [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) (example shown below). Bad news is, **I'm having difficulty converting it from `jsx` to `tsx` and doing whatever else needs to be done to get it to *actually* work within the tests.**

##### redux docs

> this is the wrapper they provide to give components (within tests) access to ... the redux store/behaviors?

```js
// testing-utils.ts

import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
// Import your own reducer
import alertReducer from '../alertSlice'

function render(
 ui,
  {
    preloadedState,
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: { alert: alertReducer },
      preloadedState,
    }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

- when I write a test in `react-testing-library`, **ie user clicks a button**, the value I'm testing for (shown below) appears as "undefined".

```js
import { render, screen } from "../../../testing-utils/test-utils";

  test.only("when the user clicks the 'click me' button, a snackbar appears", async () => {
    expect(screen.queryByText(/header/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    const clickMeButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /click me/i });
    user.click(clickMeButton);

    expect(
    // screen.debug() shows: 'undefined header' not ... 'great job header'
      await screen.findByText(/great job header/i)
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

- component I'm testing against:

```js
const SelectMedia = () => {
  const alertState = useAppSelector(selectAlert);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const createSnackBar = () => {
    dispatch(
      setAlert({
        type: "success",
        message: "great job",
        display: "support-both",
      })
    );
  };


  return (
    <SelectMediaWrapper>
      {alertState && alertState.message + " header"}
      // in tests, returns as "undefined header"
    </SelectMediaWrapper>
  )
}
```

I'm not sure where to take it from here, the `testing-utils` solution is based very close to the docs and my behaviors are very similar to what they used in the redux resource. However, I can't seem to get it to work and I'm not sure what I am missing in my implementation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the `render` function call in the test?

Comment: Have you tried this? Haven't tried it myself but maybe this can help:  https://gist.github.com/jozsefDevs/5f838481696057b34442727725504411